# xlib prevent close button to exit the application

Tags: c++, c, xlib

is there way to prevent application exit by clicking close button? the following code only hide minimize and maximize buttons but not close button...

> ```
> Atom window_type = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
> long value = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_TOOLBAR", False);
> XChangeProperty(display, window, window_type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) &value,1 );
> ```

i tried to search via google about overriding _NET_CLOSE_WINDOW but can't really find one... or a way to remove _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE from the xprop...

Comment: BTW, what exact kind of application are you coding?

Comment: Without motivation and context (explaining *why* you want to prevent application exit, which is probably very wrong; you want to be notified of it) your question is unclear. Please **edit your question** to improve it and explain what is your application (and why your want to disable closing it)

Comment: sorry, was away. my enterprise is running raspberry pi at production floor. there are some messages i want to display but not allowing user to close it.

Comment: That is a bad reason. In some cases, the user need to close it. Perhaps you want to configure your window manager to disallow that (but that makes a very different question)

Comment: i do not want every windows to be disabled close button. particularly to this one.

Comment: But in some cases, that is very wrong. Read carefully ICCCM & EWMH for a precise argumentation. And you could configure your window manager to handle a given application differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [ICCCM](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) & [EWMH](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html). You might need months (or years) to understand all the details (and the relation to [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) and [X protocols and architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture)).

You could in theory do what you want in raw Xlib. But details are so complex that you really should use some toolkit, like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/) (life is short), or maybe [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/). See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits) list.

Mastering X11 at the protocol and Xlib levels take a lot of time (the related documentation has many thousands of pages). Are you sure to willing to spend that?

<sup>So coding at the raw X11 level is like coding in assembler. Nobody does that for real programs today, and for similar reasons (too low level of [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)); too many details to care about....).</sup>

Notice that the current trend is to replace X with [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)). You could need several years to develop your thing from scratch in X11, and by the time you'll succeed, X would become obsolete. BTW recent versions of Qt & GTK know about Wayland (so the same code can work on X11 and on Wayland).

So **use some [GUI toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit)**. They are monster software of millions of lines, and there is a reason for that complexity (also, [graphics cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_card) are *very* complex hardware today; see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887959/841108) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26700202/841108)). They give you the ability to disable closing a window (because they know all the ICCCM & EWMH details).

<sup>Since you tagged your question with C++, I strongly recommend using Qt (or maybe SFML). The [documentation of Qt](http://doc.qt.io/) is excellent.</sup>

BTW, your unclear question looks strange (and lacks motivation and context). It seems that you are wrongly supposing that your application is the only one on the screen, and that is against the philosophy of every [windowing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system) (which are multi-tasking and multi-window, so multi-application, at heart). You should think your application as working with *other* ones (e.g. for [copy & paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste), which has no sense without thinking of *several* applications and *several* windows involved). And an advanced user could *always* "terminate" your application (e.g. with [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) or [xkill](https://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xkill.1.xhtml)). You probably want instead to be notified of window closes (e.g. to show some dialog when that happens). You should not even design an unclosable application (that is against all coding and interface guidelines).

Comment: thanks for heading up. i will look into the links that you showed to me.

Comment: I strongly recommend using Qt (since you tagged your question with C++)

Comment: I've spent many months and still haven't understood ICCCM or EWMH. months is perhaps optimistic.

Comment: Much less long than learning X11 & ICCCM & EWMH .... And your knowledge (on Qt) would be much more useful